# What is the maximum number of vertices of degree one that a binary tree with 10 vertices can have?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Full question as the title was a maximum of 150 characters.
A binary tree is a connected graph with no cycles, where each vertex has a degree less than or equal to 3. What is the maximum number of vertices of degree one that a binary tree with 10 vertices can have?

I am really struggling to understand this question and have not seen questions that are similar. I was hoping someone could push me into the right direction. As I understand the problem, we can only use 10 vertices. So would the maximum amount of vertices not be 10? I tried drawing it out and don't see how it can be any larger.

Comment: If you didn't need it to be connected, then you could have ten vertices all of degree one.  But as you noted, a tree has to be connected (and cycle-free).  So expect fewer vertices of degree one.

Comment: As in fewer than 10? So my number should be somewhere <10? Sorry I just don't really get what to do.

Comment: The problem might be an exercise to reinforce some material just covered in your book or other course materials.  The vertices of degree one in a tree are called *leaves*.  Start with one vertex of degree three, and then add leaves at the ends of "branches".  Repeat until you've used up your ten vertices.

Comment: Try to solve smaller versions of the same problem? What's the maximum number of valence one vertices in a binary tree with $n=2, 3, \dots$ vertices?

Answer (score 2):

Let $v_1$ be the number of vertices of degree $1$, $v_2$ the number of vertices with degree $2$, and $v_3$ the number of vertices with degree $3$, so that

$$v_1+v_2+v_3=10\,.\tag{1}$$

I’m going to assume that you already know that if a tree has $v$ vertices, it has $v-1$ edges, and I’m going to assume that you know the handshaking lemma. If you put those two facts together, you find that

$$v_1+2v_2+3v_3=2\cdot(10-1)=18\,.\tag{2}$$

Subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$ to find that

$$v_2+2v_3=8\,.\tag{3}$$

You want to make $v_1$ as large as possible, so $(1)$ tells you that you want to make $v_2+v_3$ as small as possible. Experiment with possible values of $v_2$ in $(3)$ to find which one minimizes $v_2+v_3$, and use $(1)$ to find the maximum possible value of $v_1$. (When you’ve done all that, it would be a good idea actually to find a tree with $10$ vertices and the maximum possible number of leaves.)

Answer (score 0):

For a binary tree (each node has at most two children) with $n$ vertices,

- Let $f(n)$ be the maximum possible number of vertices of degree $1$.

  Let $g(n)$ be the maximum possible number of leaves.$\\[4pt]$

Our goal is to compute $f(10)$.

The values of $f$ can be expressed in terms of the values of $g$ by
$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
0&\qquad\;\;\,\text{if}\;\,n\le 1\\[4pt]
\max\,\bigl\{g(n),1+g(n-1)\bigr\}&\qquad\;\;\,\text{if}\;\,n > 1\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
and $g$ can be computed recursively by
$$
\;\;\;\;\;\,
g(n)=
\begin{cases}
0&\;\text{if}\;\,n=0\\[4pt]
1&\;\text{if}\;\,n=1\\[4pt]
\max\,\bigl\{g(a)+g(b){\,{\large{\mid}}\,}(a,b)\in X_n\bigr\}&\;\text{if}\;\,n > 1\;\;\;\;\;\\[4pt]
\end{cases}
$$
where for $n > 1$, we define $X_n$ as the set of all pairs $(a,b)$ of integers such that $0\le a\le b$ and $a+b=n-1$.

Computing some early values of $g$, it becomes evident that
$$
g(n)=\left\lceil\frac{n}{2}\right\rceil
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;
$$
for all $n$, which can be proved by strong induction on $n$.

It follows that for all $n > 1$ we have
$$
f(n)=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\,
$$
In particular we have $f(10)=6$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I can see how to approach this problem and solve it now.